# Scala: Cast to a runtime Class instance

Tags: scala

See the following code snippet:

```
def getObject(key: String, cacheName: String)(clazz: Class[_ <: ICacheable]) = {
   Option(icacheFactory.getCache(cacheName).get(key).asInstanceOf[clazz])      
}
```

The compiler complains about the `asInstanceOf[clazz]`

Basically what I am trying to do is to cast the ICacheable returned from `icacheFactory.getCache(cacheName).get(key)` to an instance of clazz

How do I go about this? It seems that asInstanceOf only supports static types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest to your solution is

```
def getObject(key: String, cacheName: String)(clazz: Class[_ <: ICacheable]) =
   Try(clazz.cast(icacheFactory.getCache(cacheName).get(key)))
```

(see [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) javadoc for `cast`). If you know the class you want at the compilation time instead of receiving it from outside (e.g. as string or as `Class` from client code), you can avoid passing the classes explicitly by using [`ClassTag`s](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html):

```
def getObject[T <: ICacheable](key: String, cacheName: String)(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]) =
   Try(tag.runtimeClass.cast(icacheFactory.getCache(cacheName).get(key)))
```

You call it as follows:

```
getObject[SomeCacheable](key, cacheName)
```

For the first version:

```
getObject(key, cacheName)(classOf[SomeCacheable])
```

Answer (score 2):

Straight brackets,  "[]", indicate a type parameter - you must supply `asInstanceOf` with a type, not a value like `clazz`. Also, `asInstanceOf` never returns `null`, instead it throws an exception if the cast isn't possible, so wrap it in `Try` rather than `Option`. Here is a rewritten version of your function:

```
def getObject[A <: ICacheable](key: String, cacheName: String) = {
  Try(icacheFactory.getCache(cacheName).get(key).asInstanceOf[A])
}
```

Unlike Java code with the hideous need to pass around `Class` objects, in Scala type inference might make it completely unnecessary to even specify the type parameter:

```
def f(x: SubclassOfICacheable) = ???

getObject("cache", "key") map f
```

Scala can infer that A should be `SubclassOfICacheable` without needing it explicitly specified.